# How do I get level design practice?

Tags: level-design

I'm a game developer wannabe. I'm looking for 2D puzzle **games** that have a level creation tool to flex my level designer muscle.

I have Portal 2 (which has a level editor) but 3D is too daunting for me. I can think of Amazing Alex and Little Big Planet. What would you recommend?

Comment: How will you go about choosing which answer is correct? Kind of a problem with these types of questions, there is no "correct" answer (though clearly there are incorrect ones :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to list some puzzle games with editing environments. I would also take a look at some flash gaming sites. Theese sites often feature small puzzle games and those games sometimes come with an editor.

**Some casual/puzzle games with editors:**

- Elastomania: Its a very simple game but with a very absorbing gaming experience. The game itself comes with an editor, where you can make crazy tracks your self.
- When you name amazing alex, try the ancestors of it (The Incredible Machine etc.). Some of those games enable you to create levels yourself.
- Boomblox for Wii comes with an ingame editor.
- Some versions of Bridge Builder also come with an level editor (or there are 3rd party editors for it).

Comment: I pointed to 2D puzzles... Incredible Machine was awesome and I used the editor gazillion years ago. I mentioned A.A. because it's rather new and the first game I know that includes level creation (but I'm sure there lots of them).

Comment: Ah sorry... Must be blind ;) I'll update the list (though the two from casual would fall in this category, if you rate elastomania as puzzle).

Comment: Removed the unnessesary clutter and added 2 examples for casual / puzzle games

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the ones I've seen around:

- [GLEED2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D)
- [TileStudio](http://tilestudio.sourceforge.net/)
- [D2D](http://www.dannylum.com/D2DProject/index.html)

And one that I've used that help me transition easily into 3D:

- [Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)

Sketchup is pretty neat because it allows you to quickly make mockup maps (or a redesign for your bathroom lol). I used it to design a TF2 map before (3D I know), but it's really easy to use.

Comment: I was asking for level creation tools on actual games.

Comment: @KarlosZafra Sketchup was used to make levels in Uncharted 2.

Comment: OK Karlos... These tools are free and would allow you to "flex your design muscle".

Comment: I pointed to in-game level editors because then you wouldn't need to create a game engine as well. I have used Sketchup for simple 3D modelling (very,very simple) and it's great, but I wasn't asking for that.

Answer (score -1):

Here I will add games (mostly 2D) that include a level editor:

- Crayon Physics Deluxe

Comment: This question was closed because it's not constructive. Answers like this prove that.